# Jumping issue while rotating 3D cube

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a 3D cube using React Native, and I've managed to get the cube to rotate based on user input using PanResponder. However, I'm running into a problem where the cube is "jumping" to another side during rotation. It's as if the cube is suddenly flipping to the opposite side instead of smoothly rotating around its axis.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f188L.gif)

```
handlePanResponderMove(e, gestureState) {
    const { dx, dy } = gestureState;
    const origin = { x: 0, y: 0, z: -180 };

    // Get the current angle based on gesture movement
    const angleX = (dx / WIDTH) * 180;
    const angleY = (dy / HEIGHT) * 180;

    // Add the change in angle to the previous angle
    const { angleX: prevAngleX, angleY: prevAngleY } = this.state;
    const newAngleX = prevAngleX + angleX;
    const newAngleY = prevAngleY + angleY;

    let matrix = rotateXY(newAngleX, newAngleY);
    transformOrigin(matrix, origin);
    this.refViewFront.setNativeProps({
      style: { transform: [{ perspective: 1000 }, { matrix: matrix }] },
    });

    matrix = rotateXY(newAngleX + 180, newAngleY);
    transformOrigin(matrix, origin);
    this.refViewBack.setNativeProps({
      style: { transform: [{ perspective: 1000 }, { matrix: matrix }] },
    });

    matrix = rotateXY(newAngleX + 90, newAngleY);
    transformOrigin(matrix, origin);
    this.refViewRight.setNativeProps({
      style: { transform: [{ perspective: 1000 }, { matrix: matrix }] },
    });

    matrix = rotateXY(newAngleX - 90, newAngleY);
    transformOrigin(matrix, origin);
    this.refViewLeft.setNativeProps({
      style: { transform: [{ perspective: 1000 }, { matrix: matrix }] },
    });

    matrix = rotateYZ(newAngleY, newAngleX);
    transformOrigin(matrix, origin);
    this.refViewTop.setNativeProps({
      style: { transform: [{ perspective: 1000 }, { matrix: matrix }] },
    });

    matrix = rotateYZ(-newAngleY, newAngleX);
    transformOrigin(matrix, origin);
    this.refViewBottom.setNativeProps({
      style: { transform: [{ perspective: 1000 }, { matrix: matrix }] },
    });

    // Update the state with the new angles
    this.setState({ angleX: newAngleX, angleY: newAngleY });
  }
```

I've checked my code and made sure that I'm passing the correct values to the rotation functions

I've also made sure that the perspective is set correctly and that the origin is being transformed properly.

Comment: Where do you import `rotateYZ` from? And what 3D library are you using?

Comment: import MatrixMath from "react-native/Libraries/Utilities/MatrixMath";

I didn't use rotateYZ

Comment: export const rotateXY = (dx, dy) => {
  const radX = (Math.PI / 180) * dy;
  const cosX = Math.cos(radX);
  const sinX = Math.sin(radX);

  const radY = (Math.PI / 180) * -dx;
  const cosY = Math.cos(radY);
  const sinY = Math.sin(radY);
return [
    cosY,
    sinX * sinY,
    cosX * sinY,
    0,
    0,
    cosX,
    -sinX,
    0,
    -sinY,
    cosY * sinX,
    cosX * cosY,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
  ];
};

Comment: export const rotateXZ = (dx, dy) => {
  const radX = (Math.PI / 180) * dx;
  const cosX = Math.cos(radX);
  const sinX = Math.sin(radX);

  const radY = (Math.PI / 180) * dy;
  const cosY = Math.cos(radY);
  const sinY = Math.sin(radY);
return [
    cosX,
    -cosY * sinX,
    sinX * sinY,
    0,
    sinX,
    cosX * cosY,
    -sinY * cosX,
    0,
    0,
    sinY,
    cosY,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
  ];
};

Comment: export const transformOrigin = (matrix, origin) => {
  const { x, y, z } = origin;

  const translate = MatrixMath.createIdentityMatrix();
  MatrixMath.reuseTranslate3dCommand(translate, x, y, z);
  MatrixMath.multiplyInto(matrix, translate, matrix);

  const untranslate = MatrixMath.createIdentityMatrix();
  MatrixMath.reuseTranslate3dCommand(untranslate, -x, -y, -z);
  MatrixMath.multiplyInto(matrix, matrix, untranslate);
};